# EF core 6 wrong entity name in scaffolding db first

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a db on SqlServer whose tables are all identical and named after italian towns (like Roma , Torino etc).
When launching the scaffold-dbcontect command to create the model , I get a corresponding number of entities which have the same name of the tables, as I expected : just one of the entities, the last one , corresponding to the italian town of Venezia, is named as "Venezium" instead of Venezia .
What could be the reason ? I guess its a bug in EF core 6 since I have no customization of any kind in my project.

Comment: Disable pluralization (on by default)

Comment: Name of the entity class was changed from plural (Venezia) to singular (Venezium) by default. You could modify this behavior according to the following guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-turn-pluralization-on-and-off-o-r-designer?view=vs-2022

Comment: I can't believe EF core understands Latin !! :)   that's outstanding !! Thanks

Comment: Now there's another problem : the db context has been created but  , after I instantiate it , I cannot find the dbsets inside it ....

Comment: So, let create another question . Btw, if you think my comment above is useful, I will make it an answer. Then, please confirm my answer so that other people can find it if they encounter a problem like your.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name of the entity class was changed from **plural** **(****Venezia****)** to **singular (Venezium)** by default. You could modify this behavior according to the following guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-turn-pluralization-on-and-off-o-r-designer?view=vs-2022